# playing m4a files on finch

Tags: ios, aac, decoder, m4a, finch

I have tried putting in the decoding options in the decoder file with finch in order to get .m4a files to play, but it when it actually plays the sounds, it comes out static. Any ideas on how to get this work?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't play m4a files with Finch, because OpenAL doesn't load m4a files.
And it doesn't decode them either.

To play m4a files, you must use AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: I figured out how to do it by using CocosDeshion instead.

Comment: That's not right. It is possible to decode m4a-files and play them with finch/OpenAL.